# Replacing multiple elements from a vector from an index

Tags: r, indexing, gsub

I have a data frame called Main with broker names and their numbers:

```
 Main <- data.frame(
   Number = c(3,70,40,8), 
   Broker = c("XP","HSBC","MORGAN STANLEY","UBS"))
```

Then, there is a vector of deals made by these brokers:

```
Broker <- c(70,70,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,40)
```

I´d like to replace Broker elements with their corresponding element in Main and produce an output like Broker_Name:

```
Broker_Name <- c("HSBC","HSBC","UBS","UBS","UBS","UBS","UBS","UBS","UBS","MORGAN STANLEY")
```

Already tried gsub and merge with no success.

Comment: `Main$Broker[match(Broker, Main$Number)]`

Answer (score 2):

You want to mapvalues. There is a function to do so:

```
library(dplyr)
Broker <- c(70,70,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,40)
Broker_Name <- mapvalues(Broker,Main$Number,as.character(Main$Broker))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by merging?

```
Main <- data.frame(Number = c(3,70,40,8), Broker =      c("XP","HSBC","MORGAN STANLEY","UBS"))

Broker_Num <- c(70,70,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,40)



Broker_Name <- as.character(merge(as.data.frame(Broker_Num),Main,
                     by.y="Number",
                     by.x="Broker_Num",
                     all.x=T,
                     all.y=F,
                     sort=F)$Broker)
```

Comment: It should work now, It has been edited so now the output are strings

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
Broker_Name <- c(1:length(Broker))

for(ii in 1:length(Broker)) {

  x <- Broker[ii]

  Broker_Name[ii] <- as.character(Main[Main[,1] == x,2])

  }
```